Not able to add jwt as authentication in a springboot application using mysql. SpringBoot: 3.2.5 and spring security: 6.2.4
I am creating an application and want to use jwt as authentication mechanism. I have implemented the security configurations for jwt but its giving 403 for all my request.
In securityFilterChain method I have added the endpoints where I dont want authentication to be done.
I am using mysql as database and have added the info in application.properties
package com.abhinav.mangadownloader.common;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(
            JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter
    ) {
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Http : "+ http.toString());
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/login", "/user-add").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.sessionManagement(sessionCreationPolicy -> sessionCreationPolicy.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("authenticationManager");
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

package com.abhinav.mangadownloader.common;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    private CustomeruserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, CustomeruserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doFilterInternal");
        System.out.println("URI: " + request.getRequestURI());
        String token = getTokenFromRequest(request);

        if(StringUtils.hasText(token) && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            String username = jwtTokenProvider.getUsername(token);

            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

            authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        }
        System.out.println("doFilterInternal End");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    private String getTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println("getTokenFromRequest");

        try {

            String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

            if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                return bearerToken.substring(7);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}


package com.abhinav.mangadownloader.common;

import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenProvider.class);

    private final String jwtSecret = "mangadownload";

    private final long jwtExpirationDate = 604800000;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();

        Date expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + jwtExpirationDate);

        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expirationDate).signWith(key()).compact();
    }

    private Key key(){
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(
                Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSecret)
        );
    }


    public String getUsername(String token){
        Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(key())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
        return claims.getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token){
        try{
            Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKey(key())
                    .build()
                    .parse(token);
            return true;
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}

package com.abhinav.mangadownloader.common;

import com.abhinav.mangadownloader.entity.User;
import com.abhinav.mangadownloader.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomeruserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("loadUserByUsername");
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Does Not Exist by Username"));

        return (UserDetails) user;
    }
}




package com.abhinav.mangadownloader.controller;

import com.abhinav.mangadownloader.request.LoginRequest;
import com.abhinav.mangadownloader.request.UserAddRequest;
import com.abhinav.mangadownloader.response.LoginResponse;
import com.abhinav.mangadownloader.service.LoginService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class LoginController {

    private final LoginService loginService;

    @Autowired
    public LoginController(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }


    @PostMapping("/login")
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        return loginService.login(request);
    }

    @PostMapping("/user-add")
    public void addUser(@RequestBody UserAddRequest request){
        loginService.userAdd(request);
    }
}


I have used custom UserDetailsService not using roles added roles changed functions operations.

I think you code looks good. could you set security log level to debug and share your log . maybe there is an issue in your app that throw exception and spring will redirect to /error endpoint that is not added in your security Filter chain

this entire authentication is bad practice, JWTs should not be handed out to browsers. Implement FormLogin instead or full oauht2 and not this homemade security

2024-05-29T20:07:32.061+05:30  INFO 33016 --- [manga-downloader] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
doFilterInternal
URI: /manga-download/user-add
getTokenFromRequest
doFilterInternal End

Will check for FromLogin in spring security

I got the answer to my question my mistake was I was not having role in user table entity so when converting in file: CustomeruserDetailsService. It was throwing an error as it was not being converted properly so just added a dummy role and returned the answer as it is.
import com.abhinav.mangadownloader.entity.User;
import com.abhinav.mangadownloader.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomeruserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("loadUserByUsername");
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Does Not Exist by Username"));
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                .withUsername(user.getUsername())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .authorities("USER")
                .build();
    }
}

